# Exception after LinearGradientBrush.Clone()

Tags: c#

Exception throws when getting InterpolationColors property from a cloned LinearGradientBrush:

```
LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 0), Color.White , Color.Black);
ColorBlend colorBlend = new ColorBlend();
colorBlend.Colors = new Color[] {Color.White, Color.Red, Color.Black};
colorBlend.Positions = new float[] { 0f, 0.5f, 1f };
brush.InterpolationColors = colorBlend;
ColorBlend colorBlend1 = brush.InterpolationColors;
LinearGradientBrush brushCopy2 = (LinearGradientBrush)brush.Clone();
ColorBlend colorBlend2 = brushCopy2.InterpolationColors;
```

Exception throws from the last line.

Comment: What exception would that be exactly?

Comment: @Sayse exception is: Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentException: the property must be set to a valid ColorBlend object to use a complementary color. ColorBlend object must be in the same location and color value. Starting from 0.0 to 1.0. 1.0 is the last element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, Get yourself a copy of ILSpy or use another way to dig around the source and problems like this become more obvious....

`LinearGradientBrush` has a private bool called `interpolationColorsWasSet`

`InterpolationColors` is a property which calls `_GetInterpolationColors();`

which in turn starts with

```
if (!this.interpolationColorsWasSet)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("InterpolationColorsCommon", new object[]
    {
        SR.GetString("InterpolationColorsColorBlendNotSet"),
        ""
    }));
}
```

The problem is that `Clone` copies the underlying GDI Brush using its handle and makes no effort to set this private bool, so even though the InterpolationColors are *probably* set in the underlying GDI Brush. You'll always get this error.

Comment: Then, if i want to copy a LinearGradientBrush, i need to copy the InterpolationColors  from the source brush and set it to the copy brush. Is there another  way to get a LinearGradientBrush copy?

Comment: @PeytonXu Actually I suspect you could just do `brushCopy2.InterpolationColors = colorBlend` Since the `_SetInterpolationColors` method Copies it internally and Marshals it to native memory anyway